Exercise on irreducible positive recurrent markov chain
Let $ X $ be a homogeneus irreducible positive recurrent markov chain with state space S and stationary distribution p.
For a subspace A of S let $T_{k} ^{A}$, $k\ge1$, be the sequence of return times to A.
Show that
$lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty}(T_{k} ^{A} / k) =1 / \sum_{j\in A}(p(j))$.
How to show this result??
(this is exercise 6.6.27 from "Probability Theory and Stochastic Processes" P. Bremaud")

1. Let $N_n(A)$ be the number of visits to $A$ by time $n$; that is, $N_n=\sum_{j=1}^n 1_A(X_j)$. What can you say about $N_n(A)/n$ as $n\to\infty$?
2. Observe that, for each $n$ and $k$,  $T_k^A\le n$ if and only if $N_n(A)\ge k$.


Using ergodic theorem, we have that N_n(A)/n converges to sum(p(j)), for j in A.
How can I conclude the proof of my statement using this fact and observation 2? @JohnDawkins

